# load 2 model in the same controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

these my Controller

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("/admin/m_mapel","m_mapel");
    $this->load->model("/admin/m_prestasi","m_prestasi");
}
public function index(){
    $data['mapel']=$this->m_mapel->get_mapel();
    $data['prestasi']=$this->m_prestasi->get_prestasi();

}
```

it gives me an error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_prestasi() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppdb\application\controllers\c_pendaftaran.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

replace this lines

```
$this->load->model("/admin/m_mapel","m_mapel");
$this->load->model("/admin/m_prestasi","m_prestasi");
```

with this

```
$this->load->model("admin/m_mapel","m_mapel");
$this->load->model("admin/m_prestasi","m_prestasi");
```

just remove "/"

Answer (score 0):

Models can be loaded in an array

```
$this->load->model(array('/admin/m_mapel', '/admin/m_prestasi'));
```